# How to split the string and number from set of String in swift

Tags: swift

here i have some set of string. i have to take particular string continue with number

Example :

1). \n\nRanjitha, 20\n\n\"N0? yE¥ WQRKINQ Il. iM gm N-LI?\']\" ......\n\nYou\'ve crossed paths 10 times\n\nPoth btDtlun\n\n

2).\n\nShruthi, 21\n\n

3).\n\nKhushbu,22\n©\n\n

4). \n\nVanitha, 22 \'r-e\'\"\n\nC? Bishop Cotton Women‘s Christian College\n\n® 5 kilometres away\n\n

This is the format i get from image using OCR. 
i want to split the name and age separate.

Expecting outout : 1 st String - > name : Ranjitha , age : 20
can you any one tell the logic ?

Comment: Is the name and age comma separated everytime?

Comment: you can using regex get numbers see this 

https://regex101.com/r/hw4o43/1

Comment: based on the screen shot. i tried 3 screen shot there its coming the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is regular expression.

The pattern searches for

- One or more characters (will be captured)
- A comma
- An optional whitespace character
- One or more digits (will be captured)

---

```
let string = """
1). \n\nRanjitha, 20\n\n\"N0? yE¥ WQRKINQ Il. iM gm N-LI?\']\" ......\n\nYou\'ve crossed paths 10 times\n\nPoth btDtlun\n\n

2).\n\nShruthi, 21\n\n

3).\n\nKhushbu,22\n©\n\n

4). \n\nVanitha, 22 \'r-e\'\"\n\nC? Bishop Cotton Women‘s Christian College\n\n® 5 kilometres away\n\n
"""

let pattern = "(\\w+),\\s?(\\d+)"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    for match in matches {
        let nameRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!
        print("name", string[nameRange])
        let ageRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!
        print("age", string[ageRange])
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex Error:", error)
}
```